# Getting stack trace without connection to android studio via USB

Tags: android, adb, stack-trace, android-sdk-tools

Is there a way to get the stack trace without being connected via USB to android studio when the application crash?

I am developing an application where the phone needs to be connected to another USB device.
At some point the app crash, and because I'm not connected to android studio I cant see the stack.
Any suggestions how to get the stack trace after the crash?

Comment: use crashlytics by fabric. I have used it in my apps and I can say that it is quite effective with easy-integration

Comment: Actually this is very good, Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can debug an app and view logcat via adb over wi-fi allowing you to keep the usb free. It's very simple to set up and works well.
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb.html#wireless

Comment: I believe your answer should work fine, but as I mentioned in previous answer, I have some strange issue with ADB which shows that device is not connected as soon as I run the ADB server

Comment: Ah I see. Try getting adb running with USB first before disconnecting and switching over to wifi.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use logcat after the fact.  All AS does is use logcat with a filter for the process creating the messages.  That still requires you to attach the device soon afterwards.

The other option would be to use something like ACRA to set up a system to email/send crashes to a webservice.

Comment: Can you please explain the process of getting the stack with logcat after the crash?

Comment: Attach device using USB.  Run adb logcat from the command line (if not in your path, adb is found at <sdk_dir>/platform_tools/adb

Comment: That means a device isn't connected.

Comment: that's not very helping, I'm checking with Android studio that the device connected, running the adb logcat from cmd, then it says "adb server is out of date. Killing...
*deamon started successfully * 
-waiting for device- 
then I check again in android studio and device is offline.